# Why function declarations are always moved to top during evaluation?

Tags: javascript, evaluation

This isn't actually a specific issue I have but something I'd like to educate myself on:

As far as I understand, in JavaScript the following code

```
if (true) {
    function greet(){ alert("Hello!"); }
} else {
    function greet(){ alert("Hi!"); }
} 
greet();
```

outputs `Hi!` because the code is actually evaluated as something like this:

```
greet = function(){ alert("Hello!"); }
greet = function(){ alert("Hi!"); }

if(true){
    // possibly a no-op assignment, such as greet = greet?
}else{
    // same as the other branch?
} 
greet();
```

***From a language design perspective,*** why does JavaScript behave in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have found a quirk of the language and if you look a bit further you will also find different implementations.

ECMAScript processing has two phases - in the first, all declarations are processed to create named properties within the scope of their declaration. In the second, the code is executed. So declared functions and variables are available in their declared scope from the start of execution, regardless of where in the code they are declared.

And those that are created or assigned values by assignment will have values only when the assignment code is executed.

So:

```
// Call x
x();

// Declare x
function x(){}
```

works without error. This is colloquially called "hoisting", meaning declarations are "hoisted" to the top of the scope.

However, to paraphrase your example:

```
if (true) {
    function x(){
        alert('true x');
    }
} else {
    function x(){
        alert('false x');
    }
}

// In most browsers
x(); // false x

// But in Firefox
x(); // true x
```

For most browsers, the second declaration overrides the first. That is because ECMAScript does not have block scope, only function and global scope.

**However**, in this case extensions are allowed to the language. Firefox treats the above as named function expressions, hence is shows `true x`. More importantly, because other browsers treat the expressions as declarations, *x* can be called from above the code block but in Firefox it can't, you'll get an error.

The bottom line is if you want to conditionally assign a function to a named parameter or variable, do it explicitly like:

```
var x;
if (true) {
    x = function (){
          alert('true x');
        };
} else {
    x = function (){
            alert('false x');
        };
}
```

so that you get consistent behaviour. And you must also remember that *x* will not be a function until after the code has been executed, it will not be "hoisted" because it isn't a declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Named functions are created before the code starts, so that you don't have to put the declaration of a function before the code that uses it:

```
x(); // this is possible because the function already exists

function x() {}
```

It doesn't matter where the function declaration is, even if it's inside a flow control structure, it's still created before the code starts. So, there is no executable code at all inside the if statement in your example, not even a no-op assignment.

If you want to assign function declarations dynamically, you have use a variable:

```
var greet;
if (true) {
  greet = function(){ alert("Hello!"); }
} else {
  greet = function(){ alert("Hi!"); }
} 
greet();
```

You don't have to use anonymous functions though, you could assign one of two named functions to the variable.

Comment: That's actually not true cross-browser. Mozilla interprets the `if` block's contents as function statements and not function declarations, and will behave differently. Try this code: `x(); if (true) { function x() {} }` and you'll see it throws an error.

Comment: This this actually answer the question? *From a language design perspective, why does JavaScript behave in this way?* I think he knows that they are move to the top. Or is the answer: *So that you can use them before the appear in code*?

Comment: @davin - there is no such thing as a "function statement" in ECMA-262. There are function declarations and function expressions (or strictly, *FunctionDeclaration* and *FunctionExpression* - ECMA-262 10.1.1).

Comment: @RobG, you're right and wrong. Indeed it is not standards-defined, **but** it is standards-permitted. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Conditionally_defining_a_function the term "function statement" is theirs.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yes, the answer is that the functions are created first so that the code can use functions declared further down. In Pascal for example it's only possible to use things that is declared earlier in the code.

Comment: @davin: So, for general web development it's an unusable feature, as not even IE 9 supports function statements. You can't safely assume that functions inside a statement won't be defined, nor assume that they will be defined.

Comment: @davin - the MDC documentation is a public wiki, anyone can create documentation there so I don't consider it authoritative unless I know more about the author that I do about "potappo". The term "function statement" is used for FunctionDeclaration and also named FunctionExpression within blocks. I don't think they need to invent the term, they can just call it a named function expression. The Mozilla extension is to treat it as such rather than a declaration. Give me a bit of time and I'll dig up some more on this, there was a very detailed discussion about it on CLJ a year or so ago. :-)

Comment: @davin - coulnd't find the thread I wanted, but this one will do:[FAQ Topic - What is a function statement?](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_frm/thread/6306f69103ed5398/9957ead186111407?q=functionexpression+functionstatement+group:comp.lang.javascript+author:richard+author:cornford#9957ead186111407). The FAQ has links to relevant discussion. My view is that there is no need for the term "function statement" since it can be described by the specification-compliant term "named FunctionExpression". Others at CLJ agree, but feel free to have a different opinion.

Comment: @davin - note that I am saying that the **term** named FunctionExpression is specification compliant, the Mozilla behaviour is an allowed extension and non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

First, it does not always behave in this way. In the case of **Function Expressions** function object is only available in the internal scope.

Second, when you define a function it is very likely that you want to use it in the current scope. So it is very natural that it will become available in the current scope. Consider that the enclosing scope (depending on the function definition location) is the global object or the enclosing function body not the `if` block.

Now, I can reduce your question to the following question:

- Why the function name is used as the variable name?

  A : Otherwise developers have to always assign function to a variable (which I prefer).

Comment: I think you reduced the question the wrong way ;) The question is why the functions are hoisted to the top, from a language design point of view. What are the advantages of this? And he is only talking about function declarations anyway...

Comment: @Felix Kling I answered that part of question in my second paragraph. It is very likely that the developer use the function in the enclosing scope. and consider that the enclosing scope is the global object or the enclosing function body not the `if` block.